# A question regarding $Hom(X,X)$ (or $Mor(X,X)$)

Tags: category-theory

I refer to Rankeya's answer on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78980/group-as-a-category) question.

Shouldn't $Mor(X,X)$ consist of monomorphisms only, for each morphism to have an inverse?

Comment: This does not make sense. In the linked answer, Rankeya defines a category.

Comment: @Pece- How does Rankeya conclude that every element has an inverse in $Mor(X,X)$. The way I read the answer is that elements of a group can be mapped to elements of $Mor(X,X)$. Hence, $id_G$ maps to the identity mapping, etc.

Comment: Rankeya defines $\operatorname{Mor}(X,X)$, which is always a monoid, to be the particular monoid $G$. But $G$ is a group, i.e. a monoid in which every member has an inverse.

Comment: Actually inverses are also two-sided, so you need more than just being a monomorephism.

Comment: @user99680- Yes, but considering we're talking about $Mor(X,X)$, every injective morphism will have a unique two-sided inverse.

Comment: Sorry, I now understand how rubbish this question is. $X$ is not a set and $Mor(X,X)$ does not comprise of set mappings from $X$ to $X$.

Comment: @user1992 See my answer, which I hope clarifies your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf{Mor}(X,X)$ is always a monoid. Rankeya defines $\mathbf{Mor}(X,X)$ to be $G$, a group. $G$ *has inverses* by definition; hence, each member of $\mathbf{Mor}(X,X)$ has an inverse.