# Group as a category with one element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The idea of a group as a category with one element confuses me. Let us take the set of natural numbers. This set is a group under the operation of multiplication. Now if we consider the set of natural numbers as a group what is the one element that it will have?

I also need clarification on how the composition becomes the product.

Comment: $(\Bbb N,\cdot)$ is not a group. Not at all. (Only $1$ has inverse).

Comment: Your general question has been asked here several times before, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147444/group-as-a-category-with-one-object) is another instance.  Of course, as others have remarked, $\mathbb N$ is simply not a group (under neither multiplication nor addition).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that $(\mathbb N,\times)$ is *not* a group.