# Category-Theoretic Definition of an Action

Tags: category-theory

I'm struggling with the definition of an action in category theory, this is [nLab's definition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action):

> An **action** of a group $G$ on an object $x$ in a category $C$ is a representation of $G$ on $x$, that is a group homomorphism $\rho : G \to Aut(x)$, where $Aut(x)$ is the automorphism group of $x$.
>
> As indicated above, a more sophisticated but equivalent definition treats the group $G$ as a category denoted $\mathbf{B} G$ with one object, say $*$.  Then an *action* of $G$ in the category $C$ is just a functor 
>   $$\rho : \mathbf{B} G \to C.$$
>   Here the object $x$ of the previous definition is just $\rho(*)$.

The definition indicating that each object in $G$ specifies an automorphism on $x$ makes sense to me, but I don't understand how this is equivalent to a functor that just identifies $x$.

And from [Category Theory in Context](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/context.pdf):

> Let $G$ be a group, regarded as a one-object category $\mathbf{B} G$. A functor
>   $X : \mathbf{B} G \to C$ specifies an object $X \in C$ (the unique object in its image) together with an
>   endomorphism $g^∗ : X \to X$ for each $g \in G$. This assignment must satisfy two conditions:
>
> (i) $h^∗g^∗$ = $(hg)^∗$ for all $g, h \in G$.
>
> (ii) $e^∗ = 1_X$, where $e \in G$ is the identity element.

This sounds like the second definition from nLab, except that it adds the endomorphism $g^*$, which seems to make it more compatible with the $\rho : G \to Aut(x)$ definition. How are these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: It seems to me that the first "more sophisticated" approach winds up mapping the *arrows* of category $\mathbf B G$ to arrows in category $C$ from $x$ to $x$, i.e. the "automorphisms" of $x$.  Note that the single object $*$ of $\mathbf B G$ is assumed to be mapped by the functor to $x$.  To be a functor, $\rho$ has to respect arrow composition, i.e. associativity and preservation of the identity element built into the construction of  $\mathbf B G$.  Is that much clear?

Comment: Thank you, yes, that makes sense. But then why is the endormorphism $g^*$ necessary in the third definition?

Comment: It's just spelling out what it means to be a functor.

Comment: What @Berci said!  The endomorphism $g^*$ is what we called $\rho(g)$ for an arrow $g$ (group element of G) in category  $\mathbf B G$.

Comment: Aaaah. Neat! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the discussion at the [linked nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action) notes, the word *action* can have various meanings and related applications in category theory. The phrase [action of a group](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action#actions_of_a_group) is more precise, but still susceptible of two distinct but equivalent framings.

We are first given a group $G$ and a category $C$ that has an object $x$.  What is defined is an action of group $G$ on such an object $x$.  It is said to be "a representation of $G$ on $x$, that is a group homomorphism $\rho:G \to \operatorname{Aut}(x)$".  Note that this allows the trivial homomorphism, one that sends all elements of $G$ to the identity arrow on $x$.

Also the category $C$ might as well be reduced to just the one object $x$ in this context, because $\operatorname{Aut}(x)$ depends only on certain arrows from $x$ to itself.

The "more sophisticated" approach restates this idea by "treat[ing] the group $G$
as a category denoted $\mathbf B G$ with one object, say $*$."  Here the arrows of category $\mathbf B G$ are the elements of $G$, the composition of arrows is given by group multiplication, and the identity arrow on $\mathbf B G$ corresponds to the identity element of $G$.  This construction allows us to concisely define an action of group $G$ as a functor $\rho:\mathbf B G \to C$.

Verifying the equivalence of these two approaches is straightforward once the claim is established that [a group essentially amounts to a one-object category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147444/group-as-a-category-with-one-object) in which every arrow has an inverse, as previously shown on Math.SE.

We are able to uniquely identify the object $x$ in category $C$ as the image of object $*$ in category $\mathbf B G$, and likewise the identity arrow on $x$ must correspond to the identity arrow on $*$.  Because the arrows of $\mathbf B G$ are the elements of group $G$, the functor $\rho$ sends arrows of $\mathbf B G$ to arrows from $x$ to $x$ in category $C$, and because the group elements are invertible, these arrow images have inverse arrows in $C$, also from $x$ to $x$, and thus these arrow images belong to $\operatorname{Aut}(x)$.

It's hard to be sure I'm not overlooking an important point that causes doubts here about equivalence of the two approaches.  A rigorous step-by-step demonstration strikes me as overkill, but if more detail is needed I'd be glad to supply them.