# Permutation representation of group different definitions?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm just starting a course on representation theory and I'm confused by this definition of permutation representation:

Given a finite set $X$ and a field $k$, we can form the vector space $kX$ of functions $X$ to $k$, with pointwise operations. Then an action of a group $G$ on $X$ induces a representation $\rho:G\rightarrow \text{Aut}(kX)$ via $\rho(g)(f)(x)=f(g^{-1}x),$ for $g\in G, f\in kX, x\in X.$ This is the permutation representation of $G$ on $X$.

In previous courses, given an action of a group $G$ on a finite set $X$, we've seen a homomorphism $G\rightarrow \text{Sym}(X)$ is induced, and called *this* the permutation representation of $G$.

The setup seems entirely too similar for these notions to be unrelated, but I don't understand what the connection between the two is. Also, is there a good reason for calling the $G\rightarrow \text{Sym}(X)$ homomorphism a representation, even though we have no vector space structure in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: The connection stems from the representation of permutations as matrices, see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_representation]. I think it is wrong or at least highly misleading to say "permutation representation of $G$ in $X$" for either of the two closely related notions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out, in case anyone is interested in future.

The vector space $kX$ defined above has a basis $\{\delta_x:x\in X\},$ where $\delta_x(y)=\delta_{xy}.$ Now notice that with the representation $\rho$ defined above, we have $$\rho(g)\delta_x(y)=\delta_x(g^{-1}y)=\delta_{x,g^{-1}y}=\delta_{gx,y}=\delta_{gx}(y),$$ and hence $\rho(g)(\delta_x)=\delta_{gx}.$

With this in mind, we can see that each $g$ really does behave like a permutation of the elements of $X$, namely by its effect on the basis of $kX.$

Answer (score 3):

You're entirely right in noticing this connection, and this is one place (of many) where some category theory makes the reason for the connection obvious.

We can represent a group $G$ as a category with one object (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147444/group-as-a-category-with-one-object), for instance), call it $BG$. When we do this, a group action $G \curvearrowright X$ is exactly a functor $\alpha : BG \to \mathsf{Set}$ with the unique object in $BG$ sent to $X$.

More generally, if $X$ is an object of a category $\mathcal{C}$, then an action of $G$ on $X$ is a functor $\alpha : BG \to \mathcal{C}$ where the unique object is sent to $X$. For example, this gives continuous actions or smooth actions, by taking $\mathcal{C}$ to be the category of topological or smooth spaces, respectively, or linear actions (which we usually call *representations*) by taking $\mathcal{C}$ to be a category of modules or vector spaces.

So now say we have an action of $G$ on a set $X$, that is, we have a functor $\alpha : BG \to \mathsf{Set}$. Recall there are *also* functors $\mathsf{Set} \to k\text{Vect}$ sending a set $X$ to a certain $k$ vector space!

- We can send a set $X$ to the vector space $k^X$ of functions $X \to k$, with pointwise operations. Notice this is *[contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Covariance_and_contravariance)* (do you see why?)
- We can send a set $X$ to the vector space $kX$ whose basis is given by elements of $X$.
  Notice this is *covariant* (again, do you see why?)

But now, since a group action (or a representation) is a functor out of $BG$, we can turn our action of $G$ on $X$ into an action of $G$ on $k^X$ (or $kX$): Compose the functors!

$$
BG^\text{op} \overset{\alpha^\text{op}}{\longrightarrow} \mathsf{Set}^\text{op} \overset{k^{-}}{\longrightarrow} k\text{Vect}
$$

$$
BG \overset{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} \mathsf{Set} \overset{k[-]}{\longrightarrow} k\text{Vect}
$$

Now, you're considering the first case. Notice, because $k^{-}$ is a contravariant functor that we had to take the *[opposite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_category)* of our action $\alpha$ from $BG$ to $\mathsf{Set}$. As a quick exercise, you should convince yourself that this "opposite"-ness is the reason
$(gf)(x) = f(g^{-1}x)$.

We could *also* consider the second case, and for completeness, I'll say something about it.
The idea here is that each $x \in X$ is a basis element of $kX$. So each function $g \cdot - : X \to X$ extends linearly to a map on $kX$. Notice when we take *this* definition, because $k[-]$ is covariant, we don't have to worry about inverting $g$:

$$
g(x_1 + x_2) = gx_1 + gx_2
$$

---

As for why we call both of these things "representations", as I understand it, we historically thought of groups $G$ defined axiomatically as "abstract groups", and we used the word "representation" to indicate that we were representing an abstract group by something "concrete", like a group of symmetries of some object, a group of matrices, etc. This is why
the theorem that each $G$ embeds into a symmetric group is sometimes called
[Cayley's Representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem). Nowadays, though, we usually think of *linear* representations (that is, actions of $G$ on some module or vector space) when we think of representation theory, and so I believe this older terminology is falling out of fashion.

---

I hope this helps ^_^