# elementary question category theory

Tags: category-theory

Let $a$ be a loop about an object $A$. Suppose that $aa=1_A$. Show that $a=1_A$. I'm pretty sure this is true, but I can't prove it. Help?

Comment: What is a "loop about an object"?  A self-map of $A$?  If so, your conjecture is really false.

Comment: @Randall: It almost certainly means an endomorphism, otherwise the composite $aa$ doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming what you mean by a loop about an object $A$ is a morphism $A \to A$, this isn't necessarily true. For example, the group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ considered as a one-object category [in the usual way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78980/19542) has such a morphism.

Comment: What if there is a morphism $a:A\to B$ and $b:B\to A$ and $baba=1_A$. Is it true that $ba=1_A$?

Comment: @alexanderyaacov: Again no. There is a counterexample (with $A=B$ and $a=b$) in the group $\mathbb{Z}_4$, considered again as a one-object category.

Comment: Obviously I meant $A\neq B$ and therefore $a\neq b$. But don't bother to look for a counterexample. Thanks,

Comment: It wasn't obvious at all...

Comment: sorry. thanks again.